# Blank screen when logging in with Google

Tags: support, openid, google, authentication

When I am trying to log in with Google on Stack Overflow, I only get a blank screen. No error or anything.

The exact process:

1. Select log in
2. Click Log in with Google
3. Click "allow" in Google's verification page
4. Blank screen

I have tried and gotten the same result in IE 10 as well as on my Android 4.0.3 tablet (in Chrome and built-in browser). I have tried clearing the cache and disabling all extensions, but that had no effect. I'm currently signed in through Facebook which works just fine.

A friend of mine has the same problem, we both have two-factor authentication activated. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: This is similar to this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78055/cant-log-in-with-google-with-multiple-login-enabled

Comment: I've tried posting on this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-federated-login-api (the Google federated login groups), but I think my post got rejected. If anyone knows how I may contact Google directly to report this issue that would be great!